# UPDATE sql String Error

Tags: php, sql

been learning php for 3 weeks now and i find myself with a simple error that does not make sense:

I cant see what is wrong with this code.

Could someone please point me to why this is happening.

Its a simple insert and set sql query which is like this:

code:

```
$insertresults = "UPDATE usage SET message='".$message."',islive='".$islive."' WHERE id=1"; 
$insertresults_doit = mysql_query($insertresults) OR die(mysql_error());
```

the error i am getting is this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usage SET message='hello',islive='0' WHERE id=1' at line 1
```

as you can see, the variables are correct and to what i can see the sql string is correct also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name, `usage`, is actually a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You'll have to quote it with backticks:

```
UPDATE `usage` SET ...
```

Comment: this didnt change the error message :( as this is within a class, would this make a difference?

Comment: you was correct about using usage, i changed the table name and now it works. Thanks for that, i have been scratching my head for about 2 days now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$insertresults = "UPDATE usage SET message=$message,islive=$islive WHERE id=1"; 
$insertresults_doit = mysql_query($insertresults) OR die(mysql_error());
```

You don't need to wrap the variables the way you did, give this a try :) Taking a look at that error shows you the extra `'` surrounding the column names - you don't want that.

Comment: Don't wrap the variables at all then. Should work. If not, please give the new error. Thanks.

Comment: if the variables are INT then fine, but what if they are strings??

Comment: "UPDATE usage SET message='{$message}',islive='{$islive}' WHERE id=1"

Comment: @Nick i still get the exact same error if i use braces and even if i do not use the ' on int's the message is a message and the islive is either a 0 or a 1.

Comment: @Robert, have you made sure $message and $islive has been properly escaped? use: addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes from $islive

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have a single quote in the variable values. It is always better to escape it before using in the sql statement

```
$message=addslashes($message);
$islive=addslashes($islive);

$insertresults = "UPDATE usage SET message='".$message."',islive='".$islive."' WHERE id=1"; 
$insertresults_doit = mysql_query($insertresults) OR die(mysql_error());
```

Assuming both the columns are of varchar type

Answer (score 0):

"UPDATE usage SET message='{$message}',islive='{$islive}' WHERE id=1" – Nick 21 mins ago

@Nick i still get the exact same error if i use braces and even if i do not use the ' on int's the message is a message and the islive is either a 0 or a 1. – Robert 6 mins ago

@Robert, have you made sure $message and $islive has been properly escaped? use: addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string()

moved to answer (grew)

Comment: yes just above this section the trim() htmlentities() and mysql_real_escape_string() are on these variables.